# How can i customised outbound rules of ec2 instance for particular IP's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have one EC2 instance. I create a security group for this instance.

### Security group:

```
1.Inbound Rule:
    1.1. HTTP    TCP    80    0.0.0.0/0
    1.2. HTTP    TCP    80    ::/0
    1.3. HTTPS   TCP    443   0.0.0.0/0
    1.4. HTTPS   TCP    443   ::/0
    1.5. SSH     TCP    22    My Public Ip

2. Outbound Rule:
    None
```

In this situation project is serving properly.

Mailgun, Facebook login and google login also not working.

I thought that EC2 instance is not able to send request over internet. How can i configure outbound rule for particular website apis (Mailgun, tinypng, google and facebook login only).

Comment: Whatever comes inside will go outside in SG as it is stateful. If you want to control the outbound then look for NACL.

Comment: OK @Pacifist_AWS and thanks for your comment. Can you please tell me how can i configure NACL outbound rule for particular website apis ? At present NACL is in default state. Allow to all in both inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: as mentioned in the answer by @abdullahkhawer there is outbound rule but you can not only allow APIs but you can allow IP of these website. you search for thier static IPS like facebook google etc that you mentioned and add all the IPs in the outbound rule so the only these traffice will be allow to go from EC2.

Answer (score 2):

The Outbound configuration of security groups is typically left all "Allow all outbound traffic". This is because **you can normally 'trust' the software** running on your own computer.

If you wish to increase the security of an instance by restricting the Outbound security group settings, you will need to determine all required ports that software will use.

A security group is associated with the entire instance. It is not possible to assign permissions to particular apps, but setting permissions for particular ports effectively does the same thing.

Due to the *stateful* nature of security groups, there is **no need to include outbound ports for traffic that originates from outside the instance**. For example, if a web server is permitting inbound traffic on port 80, then traffic sent in *response* to such requests will automatically be allowed out through the security group, even if it is not specifically permitted in the Outbound rules.

You **should not modify NACLs** unless you have a very specific purpose (eg creating a DMZ subnet).